# Программа, которая запускает другую программу, в качестве вновь созданного процесса

Tags: c++, ubuntu, строки

Доброго времени суток!
Нужно написать программу, которая запускает другую программу в качестве вновь созданного процесса. Программу я написала, и она работает, но при компиляции выдает предупреждение
[image: предупреждение]

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Запускает как? Каким вызовом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С++ строковые литералы имеют типы константных символьных массивов. Поэтому правильно будет определить массив `args` как

```
const char * args[] = { "lab3time", "/", NULL };
```

чтобы избежать данного предупреждения компилятора.

Тем не менее данное определение аргументов для запускаемого процесса неверно, так как процессу разрешается изменять переданные ему параметры командной строки, а строковые литералы менять нельзя.

Поэтому вам следует объявить массивы параметров, а затем массив `args` как массив указателей на данные массивы.

Например.

```
char parm1[] = "lab3time";
char parm2[] = "/";

char * args[] = { parm1, parm2, NULL };
```

Comment: Процессу разрешается менять параметры? Как? Они изменятся и в вызывающей программе? А если он запишет блок данных более, чем выделено памяти?

Comment: @maestro Как - это уже другой вопрос. Думаю, что для каждого процесса создается копия аргументов в его адресном пространстве. Но в любом случае вы можете изменять переданные вам аргументы.